# Bootstrap tooltip and awesome bootstrap checkbox error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mousehover, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

So it seems that when you are using Awesome Bootstrap Checkbox and bootstrap tooltip the check icon is showed after your move your mouse from the checkbox

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-circle">
  <input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title="tooltip here" class='checkbox'>
  <label for="checkbox7">
    Simply Rounded
  </label>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript (source: bootstrap)

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
```

Here's a example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjBYaz

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: But what is what you are looking for ? To get the tooltip always visible ? That is the intended behavior of BS's tooltip btw, nothing wrong on it. I just don't know which is your goal ...